# Update of pending contribution leads to double transactions when working with localized version

Tags: civicontribute, localisation

I think I found a bug with Contribute module (tested against 4.7.30 and 4.7.31 / Drupal 7):

The following leads to double transactions, when using a localized version of CiviCRM:

1. create a new contribution with status "pending"
2. Record New Payment for that contribution
3. Looking to the details of the contribution, you will find 2 associated transactions (1 partially paid, and 1 completed).

I think that at least part of the problem can be traced back to line 3497 of file BAO/Contribution.php :

```
$currentContributionStatus = CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getLabel('CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution', 'contribution_status_id', $params['contribution']->contribution_status_id);
```

returns the localized label of the status, which leads to problem. 
by changing this to the following, the problem seems to disappear.

```
$currentContributionStatus = CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::contributionStatus($params['contribution']->contribution_status_id, 'name');
```

Can you confirm? (I must confess I am rookie at CiviCRM code).

Best regards
David

Comment: David - are you able to take the extra step and get this on https://lab.civicrm.org/